# xautolock/ssh-add can't interact with ssh-agent if launched from .xsessionrc

Tags: x11, xorg, ssh-agent, xautolock

I use `xautolock` to lock the screen and suspend my laptop after a given amount of time of inactivity. This works fine. This is how `xautolock` is started from `.xsessionrc`:

```
xautolock -time 60 -detectsleep -locker '~/bin/lockscreen --suspend' &
```

The `~/bin/lockscreen` script does, among other things, `ssh-add -D` to remove all SSH keys from the running SSH agent. This, however does not work when `xautolock` is spawned from `.xsessionrc` - the `ssh-add -D` command complains that it cannot talk to the authentication agent.

However, I can `ssh-add -D` from my terminal just fine, and if I `pkill xautolock` and then run the `xautolock` command from my `.xsessionrc` in a terminal, everything works as expected.

Why can't the `ssh-add -D` process spawned from `xautolock` spawned from `.xsessionrc` talk to the SSH agent, but `ssh-add -D` spawned from `xautolock` spawned from a regular terminal can?

`ps auf` shows this tree:

```
root     24126  0.0  0.1 105812  5032 tty1     Ss   18:34   0:00 /bin/login --        
andreas  24132  0.0  0.1  40232  4956 tty1     S    18:34   0:00  \_ -zsh
andreas  24140  0.0  0.0   4328  1576 tty1     S+   18:34   0:00    \_ /bin/sh /usr/bin/startx
andreas  24162  0.0  0.0  15944  1952 tty1     S+   18:34   0:00      \_ xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -auth /tmp/serverauth.afXu0ohTRz
root     24163  1.4  0.5 165868 20048 tty1     S    18:34   0:02        \_ /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 -auth /tmp/serverauth.afXu0ohTRz
andreas  24169  0.0  0.2 113572 10600 tty1     S    18:34   0:00        \_ x-window-manager
andreas  24203  0.0  0.7 489436 26380 tty1     Sl   18:34   0:00          \_ nm-applet
andreas  24204  0.0  0.0  20140  2700 tty1     S    18:34   0:00          \_ xautolock -time 60 -detectsleep -locker ~/bin/lockscreen --suspend
andreas  24209  0.0  0.0  22196  2680 tty1     S    18:34   0:00          \_ /usr/bin/unclutter -idle 1 -root
andreas  24212  0.0  0.0  10688   340 ?        Ss   18:34   0:00          \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-window-manager
```

My only working theory is that because `xautolock` is started before the SSH agent, the forked `ssh-add` command doesn't know about the agent's existence, but that seems very odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X window manager is started through the command `ssh-agent dbus-launcher --exit-with-session i3`, which means that the SSH agent is started right before the window manager. However, Debian sources `.xsessionrc` before this happens, so when `xautolocker` gets started, the SSH agent hasn't started and the environment variables needed for `ssh-add` to talk to the agent haven't been set.

One solution is to modify `.xinitrc` to start the agent before sourcing `.xsessionrc`:

```
if command -v 'ssh-agent' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
fi

[ -e $HOME/.xsessionrc ] && . $HOME/.xsessionrc

x-window-manager

if command -v 'ssh-agent' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    ssh-agent -k
fi
```

Comment: You're never killing the agent. Did you mean to remove the `exec`?